# How can I lower the speed of a 220-240 V (100 mA, 16 W) inline ventilator fan?

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I have installed an inline fan (220-240 V, 0.1 A, 16 W) to draw air out of my kitchen to outside. It works well, but a little too well, and is noisy. So, I would like to reduce the speed somehow, say to half of its current speed.

I am trying to teach myself electronic engineering so fancied this as a project to learn about transistors/MOSFETs.

I have Arduinos but I don't think I have a MOSFET that can handle 220-240 V; I mean the BV<sub>DS</sub> on it is 60 V max. Am I barking up the right tree here? Is there another approach I'm not yet aware of?

Comment: The easiest way to reduce the airflow is to add restriction. But I guess that is not what you want to do. Driving a 220V fan is not a good beginner project in my opinion. When things go wrong you will blow up expensive parts, and you have to be careful about shock hazards, which makes the whole process slower and more stressful. Restriction will cause the fan to run faster and use less power, which may be contrary to some people's expectation, but is true nonetheless.

Comment: First you need to determine the specific type of motor in the fan.  Generally speaking this is not a safe choice of learning project.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, and which you use would reflect whether you have any stuff already lying around, or what you can get cheaply.

a) Drop the voltage with a transformer. You may have a low power transformer with a split 110/220 V primary. If so, hook up the fan to the mid point. If that's too slow, put the secondary in series with the mid point to lift the voltage a bit.

b) Drop the current with a resistor. That will get hot, so needs to be cooled. Can you get it into the fan's airflow? That's what multispeed cooker extractor fans do.

c) Drop the voltage with an inductor. You might be able to pull one out of a discarded fluorescent fitting, they're all over the place in dumpsters these days.

d) Don't use a series capacitor. You could get dangerous resonant voltage rise with the wrong component values.

e) Triac based lighting dimmer. You may need to put an extra resistive or lamp load in parallel with the motor to get it to behave itself.

f) Build an inverter to provide synthetic AC at the right voltage and frequency. The most complicated, but the most flexible.

Comment: Any reason you didn't suggest a triac-based speed controller/dimmer switch?  You can get fan speed controllers  off the shelf; the cheaper dimmer switches might need more load than this fan will draw.

Comment: @ChrisH lack of imagination when typing this answer under time pressure, might add it later unless someone else has

Answer (score -1):

Can you please let us know which mosfet you are using its number, you can control the fan speed using RC circuit also like we have in the fan regulator other cheap way is no need of arduino just use your fan regulator it will do your work and save your money also.

But if you still want to use arduino to control the speed of the fan you can use pwm of the arduino which will give variable output and then you will need a mosfet and mosfet driving circuit which will be connected to the fan and the arduino. You can also use triac and its driving circuit to control the fan speed in replacement of MOSFET

Comment: No. Thus is not workable

Answer (score -1):

TRIAC, that is a component that is used to control higher voltage AC.

https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-ac-light-dimmer-using-triac

But for motor control have a look at https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/saulius-bandzevicius/arduino-based-universal-ac-motor-speed-controller-a4ceaf
that describes the creators journey into motor control with an Arduino.

Comment: You cannot control an arbitrary motor this way.

Answer (score -3):

Just install a 10 ohm resistor in series, such as from Dale. In gold_colored metal case with 2 mounting tabs to some metal sheet, to remove heat.

Or try 1.0uF capacitor in series. At 60Hz, that has impedance of 250 ohms and will allow about an amp at 250 volts.

Comment: No, do not use a series capacitor with an inductive load. You can get dangerously high voltage with the right/wrong values. Stick to a resistor.